# git server hosting using git:// protocol, unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE, no such file or directory

Tags: git, git-daemon

I'm on Windows using git version 2.12.2. I ran the following command within a git bash shell:

```
$ git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --informative-errors --base-path=/c/ /c/
```

On another git bash shell, on the same machine that's serving, I tried pushing to `git://<host>/foo.git` from a test repo and got:

```
[2236] unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE on socket: No such file or directory
```

What can I do so that `SO_KEEPALIVE` can be successfully set?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/304 this is a known issue that's not yet solved.